# Conditional comments dont work while loading different jquery versions (one for IE8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple web page and I have to use jquery to load the mobile nav and a backdrop behind it. I have to make it work in non IE browsers and IE8.

My code works for non IE browsers, the conditional comment I have doesnt create any error when I look in IE8 console but the main problem is it even doesnt register the app1.js file (in the console there is only html file as a part of this webpage).

Does anyone know how to make it work and connect? Thank you.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app2.js"></script>

           <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js</script>
      <script  src="app1.js"</script>
    <![endif]-->






    </body>

//my js code for IE (file app1.js)

$(".menu-btn").click(function(){
    $(".mobile-nav-header").addClass("open");
    $(".backdrop").css("display", "block");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".backdrop").addClass("open");
    }, 10);
  });

  $(".backdrop").click(function(){
    $(".mobile-nav-header").removeClass("open");
    $(".backdrop").css("display", "none");
    $(".backdrop").removeClass("open");
  })
```

Comment: The `<script>` tag in the conditional comment is malformed; it's missing the `>`

Comment: Note that when you get the script to load, you're still going to have the problem of having two copies of jQuery loaded. Anything in your "app2" code that sets up jQuery stuff may not work because its version of jQuery will have been replaced with the older version.

Comment: @Pointy thank you. I changed the script tag but it is stil not working. It doesnt load any js file in IE browsers. In others it loads the right js file and works without any problems.

Comment: The IE8 jQuery script tag is also wrong.

Comment: @pointy thats what I meant I changed :-)   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js></script>
      <script  src="app1.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

Comment: I suggest you to make a test with this code. https://textuploader.com/1ddzx This code is working fine on my side with IE 7, IE 8, IE 9 document modes. Here is the testing result. https://imgur.com/a/68zXHzr Message in console printed from JS file. You can test it and let us know about your testing results.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT thank you! now the right version does load but my jquery code in IE8 doesnt work (the code is in my question post). .backdrop is a div, .menu-btn is a button with a span and icon inside of it, and .mobile-nav is a nav with ul in it. The console says this: DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337. Do you know where ićould be the problem? thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like your original issue is solved. Further you can try to debug your JS code. Try to put console.log on button click to verify that event is executing or not. If it is executing than try to check further. Otherwise try to find the reason why click event not executing.